# wpf PathFigure to draw/show/display text

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

How can we draw text using PathFigure?

Answer (score 1):

Petzold wrote an article about: [Render Text On A Path With WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd263097.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your response. That is using pathfigure to show text on some path figure... i want in that path figure somehow i can embed my text...

Comment: I dont understand the difference